# ERROR missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, eventos

Buenas soy nuevo con el tema de la programación en Python quisiera saber cual es el error que estoy cometiendo al usar eventos:
[image: código][image: error]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Comment: Para darle formato al código puedes seleccionar todo el código y apretas las {} que estan arriba de la caja de texto donde editas la pregunta.